# Right spaced print using loop in shell

Tags: bash, shell

```
#/bin/bash

for i in {1..6}; do
    printf '#\n' 
    for (( n = 0; n < $i; n++ )); do
        printf '#'
    done
done
```

Output:

```
vivsingh@blr-mp4sj:~/Desktop$ ./staircases.sh
```

[image]

Please help me to print the right side?

Expected Output: In the image right spaced staircase

Comment: You need a newline after the loop - you could move the newline printing code to after the for loop.  Otherwise, your current code prints the desired output.

Comment: Current code prints the below:
vivsingh@blr-mp4sj:~/Desktop$ ./staircases.sh 
#
##
###
####
#####
######

I was looking for :
     #
    ##
   ###
  ####
 #####
######

Comment: You can also use `printf "######" | { while read -n1 char; do line="$line$char"; printf "%6s\n" "$line" ;done }`

Comment: The %6s formatting is not a mandate as the string will be normalized by the move pointer, I do not expect a BOGO here OR A SEGMENTATION FAULT

Answer (score 0):

Using Bash, prefix the first `#` with appropriate number of spaces with a conditional format:

```
#!/bin/bash

for i in {1..6}; do
    printf "%$((6 - i + 1))s" "#"
    for ((n = 1; n < i; n++)); do
        printf '#'
    done
    printf '\n'
done
```

Output:

```
     #
    ##
   ###
  ####
 #####
######
```

Comment: Only quibble is you won't have C-style `for` loops available in [POSIX-shell](http://pubs.opengroup.org/onlinepubs/9699919799/utilities/V3_chap02.html#tag_18_09_04_03) which could cause issues. (though some do tag `shell` when they mean bash/zsh, etc.. and given the use in the question, I think you are safe..)

Answer (score 0):

While I suspect given your use of a C-Style `for` loop, you intended to tag your question with something other than POSIX-`shell`, if you are limited to POSIX-shell, then you can easily use a `while` loop to accomplish what you are attempting.

```
#!/bin/sh

cnt=0
line='#'

while [ "$cnt" -lt '6' ]; do
    printf "%6s\n" "$line"
    line="$line#"
    cnt=$((cnt+1))
done
```

**Example Use/Output**

```
$ sh prn6.sh
     #
    ##
   ###
  ####
 #####
######
```

You can also make use of the `'%*s'` form of the *format-specifier* to enter the number of `#` you wish to output as the first argument (positional parameter) to your program using a default of `6` if no parameter is specified, e.g.

```
#!/bin/sh

cnt=0
line='#'
lim=${1:-6}

while [ "$cnt" -lt "$lim" ]; do
    printf "%*s\n" "$lim" "$line"
    line="$line#"
    cnt=$((cnt+1))
done
```

**Example Use/Output**

```
$ sh prn6.sh 3
  #
 ##
###

$ sh prn6.sh 8
       #
      ##
     ###
    ####
   #####
  ######
 #######
########
```

Regardless of whether you are limited to POSIX-shell or not, the key to right-justifying your output is to either use `printf` with the `%6s` *format-specifier* where `6` is your *field-width* which is *right-justified* by default, or, you simply need to output a varying number of `spaces` and `'#'` in the correct sequence one character at a time.

Since it looks like you can use the C-Style `for` loop, take a look at codeforester's answer for an example making use of that form of loop. (also, make sure you tag your question correctly with the proper shell to insure you get the most applicable answers)

Comment: `cnt=$((cnt+1))` can be written as `((cnt++))`.

Comment: @codeforester - good pointer, but `((var++))` isn't supported in POSIX shell. See [2.6.4 Arithmetic Expansion](http://pubs.opengroup.org/onlinepubs/009696699/utilities/xcu_chap02.html#tag_02_06_04)

Answer (score 0):

Update:

In a case where the receiver is not sharing the update window (adv_win_scale) the post expect 100 continue is not accepted by the Fourier/Answering Machine and the int CL is not revisited or pre-shared to break the movePointer and continue the char*

CL ~ Content-Length
Notes:
A proxy could be hindering the connection.
https://support.f5.com/csp/article/K94382824